# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create using Omniauth Facebook authentication railscast 360

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth, nomethoderror

Hi there I am currently following railscast 360 on adding Facebook authentication to my webapp. It was all going well until I started getting this error:

> "NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
>
> undefined method `name=' for #"
>
> app/models/user.rb:6:in `block in from_omniauth'
>   app/models/user.rb:3:in`tap'
>   app/models/user.rb:3:in `from_omniauth'
>   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:3:in`create'

I have looked at a few different answers on this website but a lot of them seem to be for the Twitter authentication I am just trying to get the Facebook working.

I have created an app on the Facebook Developers and followed the tutorial for the rail cast fully. I would appreciate any help with this greatly.

My code so far is

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
 end
    helper_method :current_user
end
```

**session_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

This is my code inside my application.html.erb:

```
 <div id="user_nav">
                <% if current_user %>
                  Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out" %>
                <% else %>
                <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %>
                <% end %>
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Going off of your call stack trace (it is in reverse order of calls), it seems like your `session_controller` calls `user` model, and in particular the user block.

Looking at your code, no error stands out, but the stack trace is flagging *line 6* and mentions that it does not understand the method: `undefined method 'name='`.  If I had to take a guess, it is likely that there is no name column in the table - this may not solve your issue, but try the following:

`$ rake db:migrate`

and

`$ rails c`

Then in the rails console, try checking the fields of the *User* object.

`> User.new`

Hopefully you'll know whether name is listed in the object or not.